# How to set Author name to excel file using poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm creating an excel (.xlsx) file using poi (java). After I create the excel file I see the excel file Author as "Apache POI". Is there any way to change that?

Here is the code I'm using to create excel file...

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /** Name of excel file that we are going to create **/
        String fileName = "C:\\temp\\testPOIWrite.xlsx";
        writeDataToExcelFile(fileName);
    }

    /** This method writes data to new excel file **/
    private static void writeDataToExcelFile(String fileName) {

        String[][] excelData = preapreDataToWriteToExcel();

        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet();
        Row myRow = null;
        Cell myCell = null;

        for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < excelData[0].length; rowNum++) {
            myRow = mySheet.createRow(rowNum);

            for (int cellNum = 0; cellNum < 4; cellNum++) {
                myCell = myRow.createCell(cellNum);
                myCell.setCellValue(excelData[rowNum][cellNum]);
            }
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            myWorkBook.write(out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /** Prepare some demo data as excel file content **/
    public static String[][] preapreDataToWriteToExcel() {
        String[][] excelData = new String[4][4];
        excelData[0][0] = "First Name";
        excelData[0][1] = "Last Name";
        excelData[0][2] = "Telephone";
        excelData[0][3] = "Address";

        excelData[1][0] = "Kushal";
        excelData[1][1] = "Paudyal";
        excelData[1][2] = "000-000-0000";
        excelData[1][3] = "IL,USA";

        excelData[2][0] = "Randy";
        excelData[2][1] = "Ram Robinson";
        excelData[2][2] = "111-111-1111";
        excelData[2][3] = "TX, USA";

        excelData[3][0] = "Phil";
        excelData[3][1] = "Collins";
        excelData[3][2] = "222-222-2222";
        excelData[3][3] = "NY, USA";

        return excelData;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 30):

It's pretty straightforward:

**HSSF:**

```
SummaryInformation summaryInfo = workbook.getSummaryInformation();
summaryInfo.setAuthor(author);
```

**XSSF:**

```
POIXMLProperties xmlProps = workbook.getProperties();    
POIXMLProperties.CoreProperties coreProps =  xmlProps.getCoreProperties();
coreProps.setCreator(author);
```

Have fun :)

Comment: Can you please let me know what is this xmlProps for XSSF?

Comment: Hello Olivier Coilland, in the case of XSSF its working good. But in case of HSSF, SummaryInformation summaryInfo = workbook.getSummaryInformation(); summaryInfo is null.. and not working..

Comment: When I execute SummaryInformation summaryInfo = workbook.getSummaryInformation(); summaryInfo returned as null, hence its throwing NullPointerException.. pls let me know what I'm doing wrong here..

Comment: Have a look at PropertySetFactory.newSummaryInformation(); :)

Comment: It may be straightforward, but it wasn't easy to find.  Thanks!

Comment: If the SummaryInforamtion is null, call createInformationProperties() on your POIDocument, it calls  PropertySetFactory.newSummaryInformation() internally

Answer (score 8):

Not a direct answer but in case anyone needs to do this in NPOI (the .NET port of POI) here is the extension method I came up with ... it's basically what Olivier suggested - only implemented in C#:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Sets the author of this workbook.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="workbook"></param>
/// <param name="author"></param>
public static void SetAuthor(this IWorkbook workbook, string author)
{
    if (workbook is NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook)
    {
        var xssfWorkbook = workbook as NPOI.XSSF.UserModel.XSSFWorkbook;
        var xmlProps = xssfWorkbook.GetProperties();
        var coreProps = xmlProps.CoreProperties;
        coreProps.Creator = author;
        return;
    }

    if (workbook is NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFWorkbook)
    {
        var hssfWorkbook = workbook as NPOI.HSSF.UserModel.HSSFWorkbook;
        var summaryInfo = hssfWorkbook.SummaryInformation;

        if (summaryInfo != null)
        {
            summaryInfo.Author = author;
            return;
        }

        var newDocInfo = NPOI.HPSF.PropertySetFactory.CreateDocumentSummaryInformation();

        var newInfo = NPOI.HPSF.PropertySetFactory.CreateSummaryInformation();
        newInfo.Author = author;

        hssfWorkbook.DocumentSummaryInformation = newDocInfo;
        hssfWorkbook.SummaryInformation = newInfo;

        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to provide an updated answer for XSSF, because the API changed in meantime for latest versions of POI.

```
var opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(inputStream);  
opcPackage.getPackageProperties().setCreatorProperty("Author Name");

// continue as know with XSSFWorkbook
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```